# Need to find the id of an element then use it as a variable to run some html

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that will fill out a series of dropdowns.

The problem is the ID changes each time I reload the page, but I need this ID to execute some HTML that uses the id as a reference. I can't figure out why this won't show me the ID of the first select object.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

var id1 = $( "select:first-of-type" ).attr('id')
    alert(id1);

console.dir();

window.confirm(1id);
$( "select:first-of-type" ).val( "2" );
$( "select:first-of-type" ).trigger("change");




});
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, variable names cannot start with a numeric literal, therefore `window.confirm(1id);` causes a `SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal`. It's probably a typo that you should fix: `window.confirm(id1);`

Comment: oh man ugh such a silly mistake. The select is waiting for an onchange to trigger some HTML is there a way in jquery to just run that html or trigger the onchange so the listener will do it automatically